# connecting samba installed os gives error "no route to host"

Tags: samba

## OS - Fedora Linux to cent os Linux

installed samba on Cent os 
connecting via fedora os

```
smb-status ONLINE

nmb-staus ONline
```

===============================

while writing

```
---smb://192.168.1.76
```

================GETS ERROR ============

```
No route to host
```

Comment: What does that have to do with programming?

Answer (score -1):

the reason in my case was the firewall in CentOs 7(IN WHICH SAMBA WAS RUNNING)

## SOLUTION(CENTOS 7)

get default firewall zone

1)firewall-cmd --get-default-zone

OUTPUT=(Public)

now allow the samba service in firewall
2)sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=samba

now RELOAD the firewall
3)sudo firewaall-cmd --reload